# Extract only specific fields from csv file in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to filter a csv file.
The format is in the following order

```
1,2017-06-27,"The Greatest View","Flume Feat. Isabella Manfredi",https://www.shazam.com/it/track/99802230/the-greatest-view,99802230
2,2017-06-26,"Onde (Sondr Remix)","Marco Mengoni",https://www.shazam.com/it/track/357622192/onde-sondr-remix,357622192
3,2017-06-24,"Right Now","SR-71",https://www.shazam.com/it/track/497286/right-now,497286
4,2017-06-22,"Tra Le Granite E Le Granate","Francesco Gabbani",https://www.shazam.com/it/track/350506679/tra-le-granite-e-le-granate,350506679
5,2017-06-22,"Upside Down","Jack Johnson",https://www.shazam.com/it/track/43748028/upside-down,43748028
```

What I am looking for so far is for a regex that would return me the output as:

```
The Greatest View - Flume Feat. Isabella Manfredi
Onde (Sondr Remix) - Marco Mengoni
```

and so on

Which regex should I use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search (with regex) for:

```
.*"(.*)","(.*)".*
```

And replace with:

```
\1 - \2
```

What we're doing is looking for a string that matches the whole line, but capturing the two things between the quote-marks into capture-groups, then in the replace we use those capture groups.

Comment: fantastic! It works

Answer (score 0):

This one is more generic solution:

1. First replace `,` with `\t`
2. Then search with Regex `^.*?\t`
3. Replace as many time as you want with `|`

Select the columns you want with column selection tool.

Comment: What question are you answering?